# AppCache Fallback when offline

Tags: php, caching, html5-appcache

I have 2 files: index.php and offline.html. I simply want to have dynamic content in the index.php (no cache on this) but when the user is offline I want to fallback to offline.html.

With my example below, Google Chrome caches index.php and when I'm offline it loads index.php - NOT offline.html (which it should) Any ideas here? Am I missing something obvious?

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="my.appcache">
<body>
<?php echo 'Online!';?>
</body>
</html>
```

**offline.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="my.appcache">
<body>
Offline!
</body>
</html>
```

**my.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2010-06-18:v2

CACHE:

NETWORK:
index.php

FALLBACK:
index.php offline.html
```

Comment: Try to remove the index.php from the FALLBACK section...

Comment: @IdoGreen Thanks, it didn't work though :/

Comment: Sorry... I meant you might need to remove the index.php and put / instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

have you solved this yet?

In FALLBACK:

Try

> Replacing index.php with /

And

> change offline.html to /offline.html

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but...
Specify in your index.php to not cache:

```
<?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); ?>
```

as the first line of your file.

in your manifest, you can take index.php out of network as the fallback specifies the handling of it.